# Use flattbuffer enum with mypy

Tags: python, types, mypy

Flattbuffer generates python code like this for enums ->

```
class ErrorType(object):
    ERROR1 = 0
    ERROR2 = 1
```

And i would like to use it as a type in a function ->

```
def my_function(error: ErrorType):
  pass
```

And if i call it now with

```
my_function(ErrorType.ERROR1)
```

That works but mypy somehow thinks `ErrorType.ERROR1` is just an int.

```
test.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "my_function" has incompatible type "int"; expected "ErrorType"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there any way to construct a ErrorType which is not int?

Comment: "*That works but mypy somehow thinks ErrorType.ERROR1 is just an int*", it *is* int. You forgot to inherit from Enum

Comment: Problem is the first thing the non enum class which should be an enum is generated by flattbuffer which is outside of my control

Comment: Can you generate your own Enum type based on the class you get from flattbuffer?

Comment: I mean maybe and i will also open a bug against flattbuffer for it but that will take ages until i can, so if there is a neat solution which would work with the code as is would be great, but if thats not possible maybe i can write some regex to update the generated code

Comment: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/pull/8145 i guess that would do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Currently `ErrorType` is a regular class and `ErrorType.ERROR1` is a simple class variable which is an `int`.

You class must inherit from `enum.Enum` class:

```py
from enum import Enum

class ErrorType(Enum):
    ERROR1 = 0
    ERROR2 = 1
```

That `Enum` class has a metaclass called `EnumType` which magically turns those class variables into the instances of the `ErrorType` which is now an `Enum` type:

```py
from enum import Enum

class ErrorType(Enum):
    ERROR1 = 0
    ERROR2 = 1

print(isinstance(ErrorType.ERROR1, ErrorType))  # True
```

Now you can pass `ErrorType.ERROR1` to your `my_function` function and it's a valid type for it.